# Select columnname, * from tablename equivalent in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In SQL Server, I can use the query:

```
select columnname1, columname2, * from tablename
```

I cannot do that in MYSQL. Is there any equivalent in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Name the table before the *, like below,

```
SELECT columnname1, columname2, tablename.* FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put asterisk first

```
select  *, columnname1, columname2 from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using aliases, e.g. -

```
SELECT t.id, t.* FROM table t
```